# How to make a javascript class array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to start a class-type arerglo in javascrip so I can call on my vuejs components my code:

```
Class Person
export default class Person {

constructor(id, nombre, apellido) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
  }
}

PersonServicesClass:

import Person from '../model/person'


export default class PersonService {
person = new Array(Person)

constructor(
) {
    this.person = [];
}

add(id, nombre, apellido) {
    this.person.push(new Person(id, nombre, apellido));
    return this.person
  }
}
```

Import component vue:

```
 <script>
 import PersonService from "../../Services/personservice";
 export default {
   name: "RegistroComponent",
     data: () => ({}),

     getData() {
       this.PersonService.add(1,"Steven","Chacon");
        }
     };
```

Error:

[image]

I would be very helpful to help

Comment: Just remove the `person = new Array(Person)` line entirely; `this.person` is a different object anyway.

Comment: looooool thanks so much, I come from typescript to javascrip

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line `person = new Array(Person)`

Answer (score 0):

Person class in JS:

```
var Person = function (firstname, lastname, age) {
  this.firstName = firstname;
  this.lastName = lastname;
  this.age = age;

  this.setAge = function (age) {
    this.age = age;
  };

  this.toString = function () {
    return ["Hi ! I'm ", this.firstName, " ", this.lastName, " and I'm ", this.age, " year old."].join("");
  };
};
```

or using Object.prototype

```
var Person = function (firstname, lastname, age) {
  this.firstName = firstname;
  this.lastName = lastname;
  this.age = age;
};

// Prototypes are better for performances if you have many call of this method
Person.prototype.setAge = function (age) {
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.toString = function () {
  return ["Hi ! I'm ", this.firstName, " ", this.lastName, " and I'm ", this.age, " year old."].join("");
};
```

Here is a working PEN: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/matrixb51/pen/vYBjzRy)

Answer (score 0):

In PersonServicesClass you have written

```
  person = new Array(Person)
```

Inside of constructor you wrote

```
  this.person = [];
```

These both are conflicted. so please delete

```
  person = new Array(Person)
```

Hopefully It will work perfectly.